# Can I mock cats Clock to return time between 1:30pm to 1:45pm somehow in my unit tests?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

I have a stream that just repeats every x seconds.

In my unit tests I want to test certain business logic, so I need my clock to start at 1:30pm and run until 1:45pm.

How can I mock this type of behaviour?

```
import java.time.{ZoneId, ZonedDateTime}
val zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York")

Stream
    .repeatEval {
        for {
            realTime <- Clock[F].realTimeInstant
            zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(realTime, zoneId)
            _ <- std.Console[F].println(s"zdt=$zdt")
        } yield ()
    }
```

Comment: I kind of remember **cats-effect** to provide something like `TestContext` that allows you to make the time pass in a deterministic way. I would also ask in the **discord** sever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`TestControl`](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/core/test-runtime) structure from `cats-effect-testkit` to have fine-grained control over time in tests. It provides a full `IORuntime`, so your code just operates as normal

See the example of advancing the clock manually:

```scala
test("backoff appropriately between attempts") {
  case object TestException extends RuntimeException

  val action = IO.raiseError(TestException)
  val program = Random.scalaUtilRandom[IO] flatMap { random =>
    retry(action, 1.minute, 5, random)
  }

  TestControl.execute(program) flatMap { control =>
    for {
      _ <- control.results.assertEquals(None)
      _ <- control.tick

      _ <- 0.until(4) traverse { i =>
        for {
          _ <- control.results.assertEquals(None)

          interval <- control.nextInterval
          _ <- IO(assert(interval >= 0.nanos))
          _ <- IO(assert(interval < (1 << i).minute))
          _ <- control.advanceAndTick(interval)
        } yield ()
      }

      _ <- control.results.assertEquals(Some(Outcome.failed(TestException)))
    } yield ()
  }
}
```